# How to add dash gridline on google chart after load?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to add dash grid line on google chart

this are the options that i'm using now

```
hAxis: {
        textStyle: { color: '#757575', },
        titleTextStyle: { color: '#757575',},
        minorGridlines: { color: 'transparent' },
        format : "MMM yy",
        gridlines: {color: '#f1efef',},
      },
      vAxis: {
        format: '#\'%\'',    
        textStyle: { color: '#757575' },
        titleTextStyle: { color: '#757575' },
        minorGridlines: { color: 'transparent' },
        gridlines: {color: '#f1efef',},
      },
}
```

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZDAy.png) is an example

Comment: Read the documentation and CTRL+F for what you need: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart. I see that you are a new user - for questions that can easily be answered with a simple google search and clicking on the very first response, maybe do that instead of posting. Google charts are heavily documented, there is no reason to not just go get that info yourself in the documentation like all programmers do first when they don't know something.

Comment: Thank you for quick response , I have read the document but not get result as expected

Comment: Show what you have tried already in the question then: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorry, my first comment to you was unnecessarily rude. You are a new user and I should have been more cognizant of that (and probably also don't comment as soon as I wake up). I am currently looking for the specific part of documentation you need. Please do edit your question and include what you have tried though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are no config options available out of the box in order to change the style of the gridlines.

however, we can change the gridlines manually in the svg, on the chart's `'ready'` event.

the issue here is that for the gridlines, google uses a `<rect>` element,
with either a height (vAxis) or width (hAxis) of 1 and no border.
so the fill color is what actually makes the line, not the stroke or border.

in order to change these `<rect>` elements to appear dashed,
we need to use a fill pattern, as follows.

```
<svg style="width:0;height:0;position:absolute;" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
  <pattern id="pattern-fill" x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(30)">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="4" height="8" style="stroke: none; fill: #f1efef;" />
  </pattern>
</svg>
```

here, we use a separate `<svg>` element, which is hidden from the page.
then we use the pattern to change the gridlines.

```
line.setAttribute('fill', 'url(#pattern-fill) #f1efef');
```

where `#f1efef` above is used as a fallback for older browsers that do not support the pattern.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'line']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Y0');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Y1');

  data.addRows([
    [0, 0, 0],    [1, 10, 5],   [2, 23, 15],  [3, 17, 9],   [4, 18, 10],  [5, 9, 5],
    [6, 11, 3],   [7, 27, 19],  [8, 33, 25],  [9, 40, 32],  [10, 32, 24], [11, 35, 27],
    [12, 30, 22], [13, 40, 32], [14, 42, 34], [15, 47, 39], [16, 44, 36], [17, 48, 40],
    [18, 52, 44], [19, 54, 46], [20, 42, 34], [21, 55, 47], [22, 56, 48], [23, 57, 49],
    [24, 60, 52], [25, 50, 42], [26, 52, 44], [27, 51, 43], [28, 49, 41], [29, 53, 45],
    [30, 55, 47], [31, 60, 52], [32, 61, 53], [33, 59, 51], [34, 62, 54], [35, 65, 57],
    [36, 62, 54], [37, 58, 50], [38, 55, 47], [39, 61, 53], [40, 64, 56], [41, 65, 57],
    [42, 63, 55], [43, 66, 58], [44, 67, 59], [45, 69, 61], [46, 69, 61], [47, 70, 62],
    [48, 72, 64], [49, 68, 60], [50, 66, 58], [51, 65, 57], [52, 67, 59], [53, 70, 62],
    [54, 71, 63], [55, 72, 64], [56, 73, 65], [57, 75, 67], [58, 70, 62], [59, 68, 60],
    [60, 64, 56], [61, 60, 52], [62, 65, 57], [63, 67, 59], [64, 68, 60], [65, 69, 61],
    [66, 70, 62], [67, 72, 64], [68, 75, 67], [69, 80, 72]
  ]);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      textStyle: { color: '#757575', },
      titleTextStyle: { color: '#757575',},
      minorGridlines: { color: 'transparent' },
      format : "MMM yy",
      gridlines: {color: '#f1efef',},
    },
    vAxis: {
      format: '#\'%\'',
      textStyle: { color: '#757575' },
      titleTextStyle: { color: '#757575' },
      minorGridlines: { color: 'transparent' },
      gridlines: {color: '#f1efef',},
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var gridLines = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('rect');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(gridLines, function(line) {
      if (line.getAttribute('fill') === '#333333') {
        line.setAttribute('fill', 'url(#pattern-fill) #333333');
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```css
rect {
  stroke-dasharray: 10 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<svg style="width:0;height:0;position:absolute;" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
  <pattern id="pattern-fill" x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(30)">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="4" height="8" style="stroke: none; fill: #333333;" />
  </pattern>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply ! This helps me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a lineDashStyle to the serie.

Like the example from: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/lines#dashed-lines

```
var options = {
          hAxis: { maxValue: 10 },
          vAxis: { maxValue: 18 },
          chartArea: { width: 380 },
          lineWidth: 4,
          series: {
            0: { lineDashStyle: [1, 1] },
            1: { lineDashStyle: [2, 2] },
            2: { lineDashStyle: [4, 4] },
            3: { lineDashStyle: [5, 1, 3] },
            4: { lineDashStyle: [4, 1] },
            5: { lineDashStyle: [10, 2] },
            6: { lineDashStyle: [14, 2, 7, 2] },
            7: { lineDashStyle: [14, 2, 2, 7] },
            8: { lineDashStyle: [2, 2, 20, 2, 20, 2] }
          },
          colors: ['#e2431e', '#f1ca3a', '#6f9654', '#1c91c0',
                   '#4374e0', '#5c3292', '#572a1a', '#999999', '#1a1a1a'],
        };
```