# Dashed baseline in Google Line chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

In a Google line chart I am using the option

```
vAxis: {baseline: 'const',
        gridlines: {count: 0}}
```

to draw the horizontal line `y=const` into a chart. Is there a way to make this line dashed?

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60780262/5090771)...